# HttpClient Post Call

Tags: c#, rest, post, dotnet-httpclient

i want to do a REST POST call, using HttpClient.I keep having error - 'RestCall.PostRestCall(string, string, string, string)': not all code paths return a value'

Below is my Code. Its meant to receive baseUrl, contentType, requestBody, httpMethod; as input parameter and return the response status code, status description and response content.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RestPostCall
{
    public class RestCall
    {
        public static string PostRestCall(string baseURL, string httpMethod, string contentType, string requestBody)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestBody).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Parse the response body.
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<IDataObject>>().Result;  
                //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            //Make any other calls using HttpClient here.

            //Dispose once all HttpClient calls are complete.
            client.Dispose();

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: put `return null;` at the end of your function

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make this method `async`? Using `.Result` is a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

You method does not return any value, so change signature to return `void` type:

```
public static void PostRestCall(string baseURL, string httpMethod, string contentType, 
string requestBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method return type to void or if you want to return any value use return statement.